# ASP.Net Menu Bar is not being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, menubar

I built a Menu Bar to my site master in ASP.net:

```
<div class="MenuBar">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            <asp:Menu ID="menuBar" runat="server" Orientation="Vertical" Width="100%">
                <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="DynamicHover" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuItem" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="DynamicHover" />
                <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="staticHover" />
                <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="StaticMenuItem" ItemSpacing="1px" />
                <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticHover" />
            </asp:Menu>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getMenu();
    }
}


private void getMenu()
{
    Menu menuBar = new Menu();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "server=(local);database=PhilipsMaterials;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "Select [Material Name] from Materials";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select();
    String s = "sss";
    foreach (DataRow dr in drowpar)
    {
        menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["Material Name"].ToString()));
    }

    con.Close();

}
```

}

For some reason the menu is not being displayed when I view the site on the browser.
Someone knows why?
Thanks.

Comment: Remove this - Menu menuBar = new Menu(); you are creating a new Menu rather than using the one in your markup directly

Comment: ok, but then I get NullReferenceException inside the "foreach".

Comment: Then you have a problem with the link between the markup and your code behind - check the definition at the top of your MasterPage (in particular the Inherits and CodeBehind attributes) are correct

Comment: This is the definition: <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %> -- any problems?

Comment: The menu appears in the Site.master design view, but not in the Default page. The Site.master doesn't suppose to affect all pages related to it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because the Menu is within a content placeholder - if default.aspx defines a content element for that placeholder then the menu will be overwritten and not displayed. If you want on all pages then move outside of Placeholder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19091/discussion-between-kevin-main-and-onca)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You instantiate a new object from menu then don't equel it to the exist menu, You don't need to instantiate a new one, just replace you function to below :

```
    private void getMenu()
{
   // Menu menuBar = new Menu();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "server=(local);database=PhilipsMaterials;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "Select [Material Name] from Materials";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DataRow[] drowpar = dt.Select();
    String s = "sss";
    foreach (DataRow dr in drowpar)
    {
        menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["Material Name"].ToString()));
    }

    con.Close();

}
}
```

And call it from **Page_PreRender** and not from Page_Load.

Comment: I tried it, but then I get NullReferenceException inside the "foreach".

Comment: The menu appears in the Site.master design view, but not in the Default page. The Site.master doesn't suppose to affect all pages related to it ?

Comment: As Onca said; However, Could you send me your project to check where are the problem.